# Having trouble including sqlite3 into my project, makefile not doing what I want

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, sqlite, include

I'm trying to make a simple database application for personal use, using sqlite3. I want to store recipes, and search them by ingredient.

I whipped up a makefile to build the project, but the linker is having trouble finding the files sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h

This is my makefile

```
TARGET = main
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -I /home/jamie/sqlite/sqlite3 -pthread
HEADERS = sqlite3.h
SOURCES =  main.c sqlite3.c

.PHONY: compile clean

#Compile all the files. The default target
compile:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS) -o $(TARGET)


#Remove all files that are produced after compilation
clean:
        -rm -f *.o $(TARGET)
```

This is my directory structure

```
jamie@jamie-VirtualBox:~/sqlite$ tree
.
├── chinook
│   └── chinook.db
├── recipes
│   ├── creator.txt
│   ├── main.c
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── recipeDB.db
├── sqlite3
│   ├── aclocal.m4
│   ├── compile
│   ├── config.guess
│   ├── config.log
│   ├── config.status
│   ├── config.sub
│   ├── configure
│   ├── configure.ac
│   ├── depcomp
│   ├── INSTALL
│   ├── install-sh
│   ├── libsqlite3.la
│   ├── libtool
│   ├── ltmain.sh
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── Makefile.am
│   ├── Makefile.fallback
│   ├── Makefile.in
│   ├── Makefile.msc
│   ├── missing
│   ├── README.txt
│   ├── Replace.cs
│   ├── shell.c
│   ├── sqlite3
│   ├── sqlite3.1
│   ├── sqlite3.c
│   ├── sqlite3ext.h
│   ├── sqlite3.h
│   ├── sqlite3.lo
│   ├── sqlite3.o
│   ├── sqlite3.pc
│   ├── sqlite3.pc.in
│   ├── sqlite3.rc
│   ├── sqlite3-shell.o
│   ├── sqlite3-sqlite3.o
│   ├── tea
│   │   ├── aclocal.m4
│   │   ├── configure
│   │   ├── configure.ac
│   │   ├── doc
│   │   │   └── sqlite3.n
│   │   ├── generic
│   │   │   └── tclsqlite3.c
│   │   ├── license.terms
│   │   ├── Makefile.in
│   │   ├── pkgIndex.tcl.in
│   │   ├── README
│   │   ├── tclconfig
│   │   │   ├── install-sh
│   │   │   └── tcl.m4
│   │   └── win
│   │       ├── makefile.vc
│   │       ├── nmakehlp.c
│   │       └── rules.vc
│   └── test.c
└── sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3260000
    ├── sqldiff
    ├── sqlite3
    └── sqlite3_analyzer

9 directories, 58 files
```

Calling "make" from inside the *recipes* directory where the project is stored produces the following errors. I'm confused as to why I'm getting these errors, since I'm adding the sqlite3 directory to my include path with -I

```
jamie@jamie-VirtualBox:~/sqlite/recipes$ make
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -I /home/jamie/sqlite/sqlite3 -pthread main.c sqlite3.c sqlite3.h -o main
gcc: error: sqlite3.c: No such file or directory
gcc: error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make: *** [compile] Error 1
jamie@jamie-VirtualBox:~/sqlite/recipes$
```

And in main.c, I have the following include:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
```

Comment: a) why are you trying to compile a header as a separate file? b) you need to use relative paths since the sqlite source file isn't in the same directory you're running make from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-I` only affects the search path for `#include` directives.  It does not affect the way source files specified on the command line are located.  At the makefile level, you also need to use full paths for header files (if you use them in dependencies in the future):

```
HEADERS = sqlite3/sqlite3.h
SOURCES =  main.c sqlite3/sqlite3.c
```

You also should not try to compile the header file, so remove the `$(HEADERS)` variable from the compiler invocation:

```
compile:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) -o $(TARGET)
```